# Using PgBarman for PostgreSQL 9.3 backup

Tags: postgresql, backup, postgresql-9.3

I'm setting up a backup strategy for a PostgreSQL 9.3 db. My job includes:

- take db backups every day/week/month
- use a Synology NAS as remote backup device

I'm thinking of using Postgres `[base_backup + WAL archiving] + [rsync to NAS]` for accomplishing the task. The db is a low activity one so I should force wal archiving via `pg_switch_xlog` or similar. One aspect of this is I would find myself with partially empty WAL files and [I would like to reduce their size (I've been suggested to use `pg_clearxlogtail`)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/66064/decrease-wal-file-size-for-backup).

Searching the Internet I found `PgBarman` which looks like a good aid in accomplishing the task but the documentation on the site assumes:

- I have Postgres installed on the backup machine
- I install PgBarman on the backup machine

I don't think I can install either of the two on the NAS (am I wrong?).

So I'm rather planning to:

- install PgBarman on the actual Postgres server machine
- use it to backup the db locally and manage eventual recovery
- archive the base backup and WAL files to the remote NAS

The main goal of the backup is not failure recovery as the Postgres server is hosted by a cloud hosting provider which ensures availability and no data loss, but rather for human error recovery.

Does this strategy make sense? Can anyone point me to a good resource to find out how to implement it? Would there be a better solution?
Any suggestions on implementing it or adopting alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated.

(I've already been suggested `streaming replication` many times but I don't think I need it and moreover I wouldn't know how to set that up in a NAS)

Comment: It can be helpful if you [link to your previous related questions for context](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/66064/decrease-wal-file-size-for-backup).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for point in time recovery (for them awkward moments when you forget the where clause  "delete from customers")

Barman sounds like a good way to go.  Barman uses built in Postgres functionality but makes managing the base backups and WAL logs a lot easier (backup and WAL log cataloger, Point in time recovery manager, manage many servers from 1 location)

Your suggested strategy sounds fine, you can set the backup location in the barman conf to point at your NAS, you can then set the archive_command in postgresql.conf to rsync WAL's to your NAS as they are rotated.

There is documentation on their website http://docs.pgbarman.org/#introduction