# Decrease WAL file size for backup

Tags: postgresql, backup, postgresql-9.3

I'm setting up a backup strategy based on WAL files archiving and transmission via rsync.

As

1. DB activity will propably be very low (less than 100 inserts/updates/deletes per day), at least in the beginning
2. I'm planning to backup remotely once a day

I wonder if I should decrease WAL file size to decrease storage consumption, because from my understanding Postgres switches to another WAL file and archives the current one once it reaches `16MB` size, which in my case could normally take more than one day (maybe more than one week); in this case I would end up loosing the small number of operations happened in between. Alternatively I could force WAL file switch via `select pg_switch_xlog()` (which in any case I will use to backup once a day) but would end up having lots of `16MB` files where probably `1MB` files would be more than enough.

Am I missing something? If not how can I reduce WAL file size?

I've also been suggested to use streaming replication but I must use a NAS as my backup device and don't know if it allows such strategy.

Comment: I don't know off the top of my head, but it looks like [this documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/wal-configuration.html) will help greatly if you spend some time reading it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I recall correctly, PostgreSQL now zeroes the end of the WAL segment after an archive timeout, before archiving the file. (Update): This is true for 9.4; for prior versions you still need to use  [`pg_clearxlogtail`](http://pgfoundry.org/projects/clearxlogtail) utility to zero the end of any WAL segment as part of your archive script before you `gzip` your archive files.

In 9.4 and above you just need to `gzip` the file, with no need for `pg_clearxlogtail`.

The change was made [commit 9a20a9b](http://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=9a20a9b), but it's only in tag `REL9_4_BETA1`, so the change will first appear in 9.4:

> ```
> commit 9a20a9b
> Author: Heikki Linnakangas <heikki.linnakangas@iki.fi>
> Date:   Mon Jul 8 11:23:56 2013 +0300
>
>     Improve scalability of WAL insertions.
>
>     This patch replaces WALInsertLock with a number of WAL insertion slots,
>     allowing multiple backends to insert WAL records to the WAL buffers
>     concurrently. This is particularly useful for parallel loading large amounts
>     of data on a system with many CPUs.
>
>     This has one user-visible change: switching to a new WAL segment with
>     pg_switch_xlog() now fills the remaining unused portion of the segment with
>     zeros. This potentially adds some overhead, but it has been a very common
>     practice by DBA's to clear the "tail" of the segment with an external
>     pg_clearxlogtail utility anyway, to make the WAL files compress better.
>     With this patch, it's no longer necessary to do that.
> ```

BTW, you should really be using an archive timeout, rather than manually switching xlogs. Consider having a streaming replica for additional protection.

Update: As Jeff noted, `pg_clearxlogtail` hasn't been updated for 9.3. The incompatibility is very simple though; the definition of `XLogRecPtr` changed from

```
typedef struct XLogRecPtr
{
        uint32          xlogid;                 /* log file #, 0 based */
        uint32          xrecoff;                /* byte offset of location in log file */
} XLogRecPtr;
```

to

```
typedef uint64 XLogRecPtr;
```

when support for platforms with compilers that don't support 64-bit long integers was removed from PostgreSQL in 9.3. So all we need to do is add a macro or function that tests equality in a way that works for both.

The following patch adds support for 9.3, but is *completely untested* so *use entirely at your own risk*. If it eats your data then sets fire to your house, well, that's how things are. [Patch here, as an attachment to the linked pgfoundry issue](http://pgfoundry.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=1011432&group_id=1000308&atid=1157).

Comment: Are you sure that is in 9.3?  I thought it was new in 9.4

Comment: Not at all sure, I was just checking that. Of course, the original poster didn't specify their version and could just as easily be on 9.1 or 8.3...

Comment: Updated to reflect version. It's one of the problems with always running master while doing dev work - features that aren't out to the public yet feel old and familiar.

Comment: I added version, which is 9.3. I was thinking of using `pg_switch_xlog` because I wanted to run the backup procedure via a shell script started by `cron`, so I thought it would be better to force a WAL archiving it the exact moment. Am I wrong?

Comment: In that particular case that's reasonable. In general I tend to suggest instead doing WAL archiving immediately to a remote server - take a look at PgBarman for a convenient way to automate this, or WAL-E for a tool that archives via Amazon S3. Using `pg_clearxlogtail` on the archives then compressing them will be a good idea, though Barman can do that for you.

Comment: @CraigRinger I'm backing up to a NAS and from my understanding `pgBarman` needs to be installed on the backup machine (I read it in the basic example), and I just don't know if it's feasible to install it on the NAS.

Is `pg_clearxlogtail` an utility I must compile?

Does it make any sense to just install `pgBarman` in the Postgres hosting server and use it to run `pg_clearxlogtail`?

Comment: @CraigRinger can I install `barman` on my Postgres machine and use it to manage backing up locally, and then manually move (rsync) backups to the backup server?

Comment: @mettjus unfortunately pg_clearxlogtail was never updated to work in 9.3.  I think the change to make it was work is pretty trivial, but no one ever bothered to do it on a program that is soon to be obsolete.

Comment: @jjanes so what would be the easiest way to accomplish the task of reducing the WALs size?

Comment: @mettjus I just stayed on 9.2, because the improvements in 9.3 were not very important to me.  You can try compressing the files without doing anything else and see how that goes.  If you never did any bulk operations in the database, the tails of the files will be zero anyway.

Comment: Re barman, you can install it on the DB server its self and just have its actual *storage* on the NAS, mounted over NFS or CIFS or whatever. Not as good as a dedicated host, and you should keep a backup of the barman config too, but good enough.

Comment: Added a *completely untested* patch to support 9.3 in `pg_clearxlogtail`. Use entirely at your own risk. Read it and understand it before using it, and test thoroughly.